# Is it OK to use table and table-cell display in css when designing for smart-phones?

Tags: html, css, mobile, smartphone

Sorry if it is such a preliminary question, but it has occupied my mind for a while and I could not find the answer elsewhere.

I have seen in several documents that it is a bad practice to use `table` elements in designing web-pages because the smart-phones are not able to render these elements properly.

I have tried to follow this recommendation. But recently for centering an element inside its parent, I forced to use

```
 display:table;
```

and

```
 display:table-cell;
```

in the `CSS`.

Now, I do not know if this is equivalent to using table element with regards to mobile-friendly designation.

Thank you very much for reading and clearing the subject.

P.S.

Here is my conclusion which I hope is not primarily opinion-based:

According to the reference provided by Mark, Based on the fact that all major mobile(and desktop) browsers support `table` and `table-cell`, then we could say it is ok.

Comment: Yes, you can use them. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

Comment: @Mark, thanks mark, it seems that only IE7- does not support it

Comment: Yep. Nobody's going to be using IE7 on mobile, so don't worry about it.

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify *what you are asking*, not to comment on answers. Questions like “Is it OK to...” tend to be primarily opinion-based especially when you do not specify what are the criteria for being OK.

Comment: How on earth a question about using some particular css rule could be opinion based?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the same problems using `display: table` as you do with using actual tables on a small screen.

Most data tables take up a significant number of horizontal pixels, so don't fit well when the display is not very wide.

The problem is caused by having `display: table` — it doesn't matter if you have it because you use CSS to set it explicitly or if you use HTML to set it implicitly (i.e. by using an actual table element).

Use a `<table>` for tabular data. Use `display: table` for non-tabular data that you want to render in a table-like fashion. Test the results on a small display and use media queries to `display` in some other way if the results are poor.

---

If you just want to centre something, that `display: table` should be OK … but I'd consider looking into Flexbox instead.

Comment: When I use display:table to center a div element, I would have a table with just one row and one column, so I think there would not be any space problem. Then could I say it is prefered approach comparing to Flex, (Flex has fewer support than display:table)

Answer (score 1):

I think that would be a good idea to use divs with class table and some divs with class td
for cells
E.g.

```
    <div id="table">
<div class="td">Something goes here</div>
    </div>

CSS:
.table{
border:2px solid red;
padding: 4px;

}

.td{
text-align:center;}
.td > *{
display:block;
margin:auto;
}
```

Everything inside td class is centered(including text and everything else}
This is why I am using .td > *